# Is it possible to use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE in producer side? - JMS

Tags: jms

Is it possible to use `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` in producer side in JMS? Then what does it mean? I mean acknowledging is something in consumer side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, message acknowledgement is purely a consumer side concept. When creating a JMS Session you have the choice among several acknowledgment modes. The idea behind message acknowledgement has to do with the concept of guaranteed delivery in message oriented middleware (MOM). In short, when you send a message via a MOM implementation, that message will be persisted (by the producer) until it is sent to a consumer AND the consumer acknowledges its delivery (or until the message expires). In the event that an acknowledgement is not received by the consumer within some reasonable amount of time the message is re-sent by the producer. Each mode impacts message delivery differently.

In AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode, any messages received by consumers through the session will be acknowledged automatically by the consumers underlying JMS runtime upon reception.

In CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode, each message received by consumers through the session must be explicitly acknowledged. This means that the responsibility of acknowledging a message falls on the application instead of the JMS runtime. Typically the consumer needs to invoke the `acknowledge()` method on the session after processing the message in the `onMessage()` method.

There is also a DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE setting that is similar to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE but instead acknowledgements are sent by the JMS implementation lazily, potentially causing duplicate reception of messages.

Typically you would use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode when you need to have explicit control over the acknowledgement of messages.